# expectation associated with Wishart distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, wishart-distribution

Suppose that $W$ follows the Wishart distribution with parameter $\Sigma$ and d.f. $n$.

Then, I would like to know the result of the following expectations.

$E[tr(WAWB)tr(WC)]$

$E[tr(WAWB)tr(WCWD)]$

where $A,B,C,D$ are fixed matrices. Are there any books or papers that derive this result?